# Download all blobs within an Azure Storage container

Tags: python, bash, azure, containers

I've managed to write a python script to list out all the blobs within a container.

```
import azure
from azure.storage.blob import BlobService
from azure.storage import *

blob_service = BlobService(account_name='<CONTAINER>', account_key='<ACCOUNT_KEY>')


blobs = []
marker = None
while True:
    batch = blob_service.list_blobs('<CONAINER>', marker=marker)
    blobs.extend(batch)
    if not batch.next_marker:
        break
    marker = batch.next_marker
for blob in blobs:
    print(blob.name)
```

Like I said this only lists the blobs that I want to download. I've moved onto the Azure CLI to see if that could aid in what I want to do. I'm able to download a single blob with

```
azure storage blob download [container]
```

it then prompts me specify a blob which I can grab from the python script. The way I would have to download all those blobs is to copy and paste them into the prompt after the command used above. Is there a way I can either:

**A**. Write a bash script to iterate through the list of blobs by executing the command, then pasting the next blob name in the prompt.

**B**. Specify to download the container in either the python script or Azure CLI. Is there something I'm not seeing to download the whole container?

Comment: Have you tried downloading the blobs using `blob_service.download_blob_to_path`? Please see an example here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage/#download-blobs.

Answer (score 5):

@gary-liu-msft solution is correct. I made some more changes to the same, now the code can iterate through the containers and the folder structure in it (PS - there are no folders in containers, just path), check if the same directory structure exists in client and if not then create that directory structure and download the blobs in those path. It supports the long paths with embedded sub directories.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
from azure.storage.blob import PublicAccess
import os

#name of your storage account and the access key from Settings->AccessKeys->key1
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='storageaccountname', account_key='accountkey')

#name of the container
generator = block_blob_service.list_blobs('testcontainer')

#code below lists all the blobs in the container and downloads them one after another
for blob in generator:
    print(blob.name)
    print("{}".format(blob.name))
    #check if the path contains a folder structure, create the folder structure
    if "/" in "{}".format(blob.name):
        print("there is a path in this")
        #extract the folder path and check if that folder exists locally, and if not create it
        head, tail = os.path.split("{}".format(blob.name))
        print(head)
        print(tail)
        if (os.path.isdir(os.getcwd()+ "/" + head)):
            #download the files to this directory
            print("directory and sub directories exist")
            block_blob_service.get_blob_to_path('testcontainer',blob.name,os.getcwd()+ "/" + head + "/" + tail)
        else:
            #create the diretcory and download the file to it
            print("directory doesn't exist, creating it now")
            os.makedirs(os.getcwd()+ "/" + head, exist_ok=True)
            print("directory created, download initiated")
            block_blob_service.get_blob_to_path('testcontainer',blob.name,os.getcwd()+ "/" + head + "/" + tail)
    else:
        block_blob_service.get_blob_to_path('testcontainer',blob.name,blob.name)
```

The same code is also available here https://gist.github.com/brijrajsingh/35cd591c2ca90916b27742d52a3cf6ba

Answer (score 4):

Since @brij-raj-singh-msft answer, Microsoft released Gen2 version of Azure Storage Blobs client library for Python. (code below is tested with Version 12.5.0)
This snippet is tested on 9/25/2020

```py
import os
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient,ContainerClient, BlobClient
import datetime

# Assuming your Azure connection string environment variable set.
# If not, create BlobServiceClient using trl & credentials.
#Example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobserviceclient 

connection_string = os.getenv("AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING")

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connection_string) 
# create container client
container_name = 'test2'
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)

#Check if there is a top level local folder exist for container.
#If not, create one
data_dir ='Z:/azure_storage'
data_dir = data_dir+ "/" + container_name
if not(os.path.isdir(data_dir)):
    print("[{}]:[INFO] : Creating local directory for container".format(datetime.datetime.utcnow()))
    os.makedirs(data_dir, exist_ok=True)
    
#code below lists all the blobs in the container and downloads them one after another
blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()
for blob in blob_list:
    print("[{}]:[INFO] : Blob name: {}".format(datetime.datetime.utcnow(), blob.name))
    #check if the path contains a folder structure, create the folder structure
    if "/" in "{}".format(blob.name):
        #extract the folder path and check if that folder exists locally, and if not create it
        head, tail = os.path.split("{}".format(blob.name))
        if not (os.path.isdir(data_dir+ "/" + head)):
            #create the diretcory and download the file to it
            print("[{}]:[INFO] : {} directory doesn't exist, creating it now".format(datetime.datetime.utcnow(),data_dir+ "/" + head))
            os.makedirs(data_dir+ "/" + head, exist_ok=True)
    # Finally, download the blob
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob.name)
    dowlload_blob(blob_client,data_dir+ "/"+blob.name)

def dowlload_blob(blob_client, destination_file):
    print("[{}]:[INFO] : Downloading {} ...".format(datetime.datetime.utcnow(),destination_file))
    with open(destination_file, "wb") as my_blob:
        blob_data = blob_client.download_blob()
        blob_data.readinto(my_blob)
    print("[{}]:[INFO] : download finished".format(datetime.datetime.utcnow()))
```

The same code is also available here https://gist.github.com/allene/6bbb36ec3ed08b419206156567290b13

Answer (score 2):

I made a [Python wrapper](https://pypi.org/project/azurebatchload/) for the Azure CLI which enables us to do downloads / uploads in batches. This way we can download a complete container or certain files from a container.

To install:

```
pip install azurebatchload
```

```py
from azurebatchload import Download

Download(
   destination='../pdfs',
   source='blobcontainername',
   extension='.pdf'
).download()
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it seems we cannot directly download all the blobs from a container with a single API. And we can get all the available operations with blobs at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179377.aspx.

So we can list the [`ListGenerator`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure/storage/models.py#L40) of blobs, then download the blobs in loop. E.G.:

```
result = blob_service.list_blobs(container)
for b in result.items:
    r = blob_service.get_blob_to_path(container,b.name,"folder/{}".format(b.name))
```

## update

import blockblob service when using [azure-storage-python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python):

`from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService`

Comment: Thanks! I added in my container name where you have `container` in your example, but I'm receiving this error for some reason: `AttributeError: 'BlobEnumResults' object has no attribute 'items'`

Comment: It seem you are using [azure-sdk-for-python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python), to handle Azure storage in python, please try to use [azure-storage-python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python) SDK instead. And the import blob service is a little different with the other one, please refer my update.

Comment: Thanks for your update and help! I ran into a another problem. I uninstalled the Azure SDK (not sure if that was required) and installed Azure Storage Python like you mentioned. The only imports I have right now are `import azure` and `from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlob Service`. Here is the full code for my script: http://pastebin.com/HbUygsq3 Running `python3 script.py` gives me the error: `NameError: name 'BlobService' is not defined`. This seems to happen from when I defined my container and account key from using the SDK.

Comment: According your code, you import model like `from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService` but invoke in `blob_service = BlobService()`, please try to [`BlockBlobService()`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure/storage/blob/blockblobservice.py#L61) function instead.

Comment: Have you solved your issue now? Is there any new issue?

Comment: Hey sorry, took a step back on this. I'm now receiving this error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '00065faa-1ef8-4eef-b0a7-5ecc26536dc4/image.jpg'` I'm not sure if I understand the file structure of how the blobs are grabbed. I removed `folder/` from your example to match my structure as such: `r = blob_service.get_blob_to_path(container, b.name, "{}".format(b.name))` It's saying file not found but it can list the file, which is confusing me.

Comment: Please refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure/storage/blob/baseblobservice.py#L1608 for the details of `get_blob_to_path()` function. The 3rd param is the **path of file to write out to**. And It seems that your blob name contains delimiter `/` which is treated as file system directory in python. So you can modify the 3rd param to whatever else e.g. `image.jpg` for test.

Comment: Ok I now understand that the third param is for the file output. What if I just want to take everything that is listed and just get all of that into a directory without specifying how the output should be?

Comment: There is not method to directly download all the blobs in a container. You can use `list_blobs` then download the blobs in loop. Also you can set the output path with your own logic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple script (PowerShell) that will iterate through a single container and download everything in there to the $Destination you provide

```html
# 
# Download All Blobs in a Container
# 

# Connect to Azure Account
Connect-AzAccount

# Set Variables
$Destination="C:\Software"
$ResourceGroupName = 'resource group name'
$ContainerName = 'container name'
$storageAccName = 'storage account name'

# Function to download all blob contents
Function DownloadBlobContents
{
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Download blob contents from storage container.."
    # Get the storage account  
    $StorageAcc = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccName
    # Get the storage account context
    $Ctx = $StorageAcc.Context
    # Get all containers
    $Containers = Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $Ctx
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Magenta $Container.Name "Creating or checking folder presence"
    # Create or check folder presence
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $Destination -Force
    # Get the blob contents from the container
    $BlobConents = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -Context $Ctx
    # Loop through each blob and download each one until they are all complete
    foreach($BlobConent in $BlobConents)
    {
        # Download the blob content
        Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Container $ContainerName -Context $Ctx -Blob $BlobConent.Name -Destination $Destination -Force
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Downloaded a blob content"
    }
}

DownloadBlobContents
```

Something I would like to learn is to not have to use the Connect-AzAccount but instead call the keys to the storage account therefore I can run this without having to authenticate in

Comment: What are the benefits of this approach over the existing approaches previously proposed?

Comment: Answering the original post "Download all blobs within an Azure Storage container"

I couldn't find a PowerShell solution and this article was high on the Google list so I wanted to provide a solid solution to the subject.