# How to download all files from a blob container using python

Tags: python

I have to mention that i barely know anything to python. I use an application that has no native support for downloading data from blop's. But it support python.

I have found a way to list all blop's within the container.
But I have no clue how to download them.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, ContainerClient
import io
from io import StringIO 
import pandas as pd
from csv import reader

sas_url = r'https://ubftp.blob.core.windows.netxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
container = ContainerClient.from_container_url(sas_url, delimiter='/')
blob_list = container.list_blobs()

for index, blob in enumerate(blob_list):
#for blob in blob_list:
    #print(list(blob.keys()))
    print(type(blob_name),blob['name'])
    blob_name = blob['name']
```

It list's all the blops within every subfolder.

What do I add to the code to download them?
Or read them into a dataframe?

Kind regards

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37079951/download-all-blobs-within-an-azure-storage-container

Comment: I have looked into this link already, but I must admit I have no idea how to translate what they are writing and apply that to my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is may be what you are looking for:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python?tabs=managed-identity%2Croles-azure-portal%2Csign-in-azure-cli#download-blobs

```
# Download the blob to a local file
# Add 'DOWNLOAD' before the .txt extension so you can see both files in the data directory
download_file_path = os.path.join(local_path, str.replace(local_file_name ,'.txt', 'DOWNLOAD.txt'))
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container= container_name) 
print("\nDownloading blob to \n\t" + download_file_path)

with open(file=download_file_path, mode="wb") as download_file:
 download_file.write(container_client.download_blob(blob.name).readall())
```