# Azure blob storage directory download (win, python)

Tags: python, azure

My goal is to download part of the blob storage that looks like a directory inside other directories.

Official [Download to a file path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-download-python) function request a self argument that I don't get how to use and other stack overflow questions often suggest [outdated solutions implementing BlockBlobService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37079951/download-all-blobs-within-an-azure-storage-container). I also found  [this](https://gist.github.com/amalgjose/7de7b93a326e5a6f53f8b43ba5187932) but it seems not work.

Generally, it seems that I have to loop over `blob_list` but I have trouble to recreate locally structure of a "directory" in blob storage for different reasons. Sometimes I have .parquet files that are actually folders with snappy compression and etc.
So far I have this code:

```
import pathlib
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container="container_name")
blob_list = container_client.list_blobs("dir_1/sub_dir_2/desired_dir/")
local_directory = pathlib.Path("local_directory/")

for blob in blob_list:
    local_file_path = local_directory / pathlib.Path(blob.name) 
    local_file_path.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    with open(local_file_path, "wb") as local_file:
        print('yes it is downloaded')
        blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob)
        blob_data = blob_client.download_blob()
        blob_data.readinto(local_file)
```

What is current best way to download a sub_directory to mirror structure on azure blob storage on win machine ?

Answer (score 2):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to achieve this using `os` module. Below is the complete code that worked for me.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import os

ACCOUNT_NAME = "<YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME>"
CONTAINER_NAME = "<CONTAINER>"

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string("<STORAGE_ACCOUNT_CONNECTION_STRING>")
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(CONTAINER_NAME)

local_path = "C:\\Users\\<YOUR_PATH>\\Downloads\\folder"
for blob in container_client.list_blobs():
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob)
    blob_props = blob_client.get_blob_properties()
    download_path = os.path.join(local_path+"\\"+"\\".join(blob.name.split("/")[1:-1]), blob.name.split("/")[-1])
    if(os.path.exists(local_path+"\\"+"\\".join(blob.name.split("/")[1:-1]))):
        with open(download_path, "wb") as download_file:
            download_stream = blob_client.download_blob()
            download_file.write(download_stream.readall())
            print(f"Downloaded blob: {blob.name}")
    else:
        os.makedirs(local_path+"\\"+"\\".join(blob.name.split("/")[1:-1]))
        with open(download_path, "wb") as download_file:
            download_stream = blob_client.download_blob()
            download_file.write(download_stream.readall())
            print(f"Downloaded blob: {blob.name}")
```

In Storage Account:

[image]

Here the path is taken from dir2 to the location of the file.

Local Results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you greatly for the reply! I had to add a container subdirectory to `.list_blobs():` and this narrowed down selection as I wanted. BUT I still am getting the error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\<loca_path>\\new_file.parquet\\_SUCCESS'`

Comment: @euh, Have you tried the same code? if not, can you add what you have tried in the question

Comment: yes almost, I have tried your code but with one modification in the for loop instead of `for blob in container_client.list_blobs():` i have used `for blob in container_client.list_blobs('dir/subdir/'):` to loop over specific directory. it seems to work but in there i have Parquet tables snappy compressed which are ending in `.parquet` but kindof folders themselves, maybe that is causing the issue

Comment: Can you add structure of the folders that you are trying?

Comment: yes it is simply `<container>/main_dir/sub_dir/target_dir/` and target_dir contains multiple `.parquet` files-folders made with snappy compression as i mentioned previously. each of those `.parquet`s has several metadata binary files (like the one with `_SUCESS` that has 0 KB size and give me an error when i try to download blob in the loop) and actual `.parquet` files (so `.parquet` file/folder has inside binary files and other actual `.parquet` files_